# Hölder space continuously embeds into $L^2$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $S^n$ is the unit sphere of $R^{n+1}.$ Give $\alpha\in (0,1),$ does there exist a constant $c_{n,\alpha}>0$ such that

$$\|f\|_{L^{2}(S^n)}\leq c_{n,\alpha}\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(S^n)}?$$

The definition of the Hölder norm is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).

Comment: $\| f \|_{C^{0,\alpha}} \leq \| f \|_{C^0}=\| f \|_{L^\infty}$ and $S^n$ has finite measure. Can you conclude?

Comment: @Ian $$ \|f\|_{C^0} \le \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$$ 
holds. And we need it that way :)

Comment: Er, yes, typo. My bad. @timhortons: reverse the inequality above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f \in C^{0,\alpha}(S^n)$, $f$ is continuous, hence bounded on the compact set $S^n$. We have 
\begin{align*}
  \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|} \n{f}_{L^2(S^n)} &= \left(\int_{S^n} |f|^2 \, d\mathrm{vol}\right)^{1/2}\\ 
    &\le \n f_{C^0(S^n)} \mathop{vol}(S^n)^{1/2}\\
    &\le \mathop{vol}(S^n)^{1/2} \cdot \n f_{C^{0,\alpha}(S^n)}
\end{align*}

Comment: I cannot see why $\|f\|_{C^{0}}\leq \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}}?$

Comment: $\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} = \|f\|_{C^0} + [f]_{C^{0,\alpha}}$

Comment: ah, sure, thanks.